Which is best wifi pci card to support linux for assembled pc
I am using an assembled personal computer.
MSI B350 Gaming plus.
AMD Ryzen 5 1600
32GB ram corsair
I am using Ubuntu 22.04, I have TP link 881nd, which is not provided drivers for Linux.
Ubuntu is freezing until I'm using TP-link PCI Express.
Is there a Wi-Fi PCI card to solve my problem.

Intel wireless cards generally performance well with Linux, including Ubuntu. Intel offers cards for both the Wi-Fi 6E and the recently released Wi-Fi 7 standard.
Any of the cards listed on their page should work; however, since your motherboard only has one M.2 slot, you may choose to opt for a PCI-e to M.2 adapter (especially if you don't already have antennas on hand.) I recommend just going to Amazon (or a similar site of your choosing) and picking whatever's cheap, since they're basically all functionally identical. Here's some selections based on what's around at the moment:
Intel AX210 (Wi-Fi 6E) with PCI-e card - $26

Intel BE200 (Wi-Fi 7) without PCI-e card - $37


This shouldn't be an issue for OP's usecase, but Intel Wi-Fi cards do not support Access-Point mode on Linux. You can connect to other AP, but not be one.
